# Firebase : Firestore : What is the equivalent of ChildEventListener found in Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have this for Firestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore   db  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference ref = db.collection("app/appdata/notifications");
        ref.addSnapshotListener((snapshot, e) -> {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentSnapshot x : snapshot.getDocuments()) {
                System.out.println(x.getData());
            }
        });
```

But I don't want to use that loop, instead I need to only get the new children. I'd like something like the following as seen in the Realtime Db.

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        Post newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        System.out.println("Author: " + newPost.author);
        System.out.println("Title: " + newPost.title);
        System.out.println("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Also in Firestore, all your data consists of documents (which are basically key-value stores) and collections (which are collections of documents). So both the Realtime Database and Firestore have some basic differences.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `.getDocumentChanges()` on the QuerySnapshot object to get the list of changes since the last snapshot. This is equivalent to the child-change events in Realtime Database.  For example:

```
FirebaseFirestore   db  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference ref = db.collection("app/appdata/notifications");
ref.addSnapshotListener((snapshot, e) -> {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
        switch (dc.getType()) {
            case ADDED:
                // handle added documents...
                break;
            case MODIFIED:
                // handle modified documents...
                break;
            case REMOVED:
                // handle removed documents...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots for more details.

Comment: At least for me, it worked exactly as in `addChildEventListener()`. I thought  it would loop through the documents, but there is no loop. It only loops when called for the first time in `case ADDED`. After first call, it just notifies in case of **added**, **modified** and **removed**.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it.

First, init a DocumentReference as:

```
DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("yourData/notifications");
```

Now using your mDocRef, call `addSnapshotLisetener()` creating new EventListener for the DocumentSnapshot like this:

```
    mDocRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            //todo your code
        }
    });
```

So this will grab your data first time you set it up and also every time the data gets updated.

Also if you pass your Activity as a context, it will automatically detach when your activity stops.

```
..addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()...
```

Comment: On your reference, you're listening to "sampleData/yourData", not "sampleData/yourData/notifications".

Comment: Now, that will produce an error, the reference has to have an odd number of paths.

Comment: What I am pointing here is that the equivalent of ChildEventListener in Firestore would be something like the `addSnapshotListener`. and yes the number of segments must be an even number